# Import statement outside a module React Library

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, rollup

I'm working on a react library with typescript and I am facing multiple self-contradictory import issues in the bundling process (for which I am using **Rollup**).

My primary dependency is **Material UI** and ESM which also contains some CJS utilities for internal use I guess, so I need to be able to use both imports and requirements.

In my `rollup.config.js` I have targets for CJS and ESM formats.

```
{ 
    input: "index.ts", 
    output: [
        { 
            file: packageJson.main, 
            format: 'cjs', 
            sourcemap: true 
        },
        { 
            file: packageJson.module, 
            format: 'esm', 
            sourcemap: true 
        }
    ], 
    plugins: [
        external(), 
        commonjs(), 
        typescript({ tsconfig: './tsconfig.json' }),
        terser()
    ] 
}
```

Both formats throw errors when importing anything from Material UI.

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles/index.js';
```

## Errors

**ESM using ESNext**

- ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT when trying to import without a file extension.
- The requested module is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports, when adding file extension.

**CJS**

- Cannot use import statements outside a module inside Material UI internal imports which I can't modify for obvious reasons.

I'm so confused about these errors as it seems none of the possible configurations work with MaterialUI as a dependency.

tsconfig.ts

```
"target": "ES5",
"module": "ESNext",
"jsx": "react",
"sourceMap": true,
"outDir": "dist",
"strict": true,
"moduleResolution": "node",
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
"skipLibCheck": true,
"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
"declaration": true,
"declarationDir": "dist/types",
"emitDeclarationOnly": true,
```